# Was there any issue with the auditing system for its military in China prior before the recent change?

Tags: china, military, government

> The Central Military Commission has taken direct control of the PLA's
> audit office, the Defence Ministry announced yesterday, a move experts
> said would strengthen President Xi Jinping's campaign to root out
> graft in the army.
>
> The office was supervised by the military's General Logistics
> Department, which has come under scrutiny since its deputy chief, Gu
> Junshan , was charged with crimes including bribery and embezzlement.
>
> Gu was reportedly a close ally of disgraced retired top general Xu
> Caihou, who is expected to be indicted soon on bribery charges.
>
> The decision to change oversight of the office was made at a meeting
> on reforming the military's audit system and attended by top brass in
> Beijing yesterday, the ministry said. The order was signed by Xi, who
> is chairman of the CMC.

https://archive.ph/w5vht#selection-811.0-825.232

Was there any issue with the auditing system for its military in China prior before the recent change? It seems that the Chinese leadership decided to overhaul the system after it was found that there was corruption within the military, was there any systemic issue in the auditing system before the change?